# How to disable autocomplete on react native paper TextInput? with autoComplete="off" render autocomplete="noop" on the web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web, autocomplete

I am trying to disable the `autocomplete` on the web using [`TextInput`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html) from [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper) 3.10.1

```
<TextInput
  name="city"
  textContentType="addressCity"
  autoComplete="off"
  mode="outlined"
/>
```

The `autoComplete="off"` is replaced with `autocomplete="noop"` in the rendered HTML, which cause the auto complete not to be disabled.

[image]

From where does the `noop` come from and how can I disable the autocomplete?

### Reproduction

https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/curious-pizza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextInput in `react-native-web` [API](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/text-input/) says it follows [The HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete), but it doesn't work. It does however seem to follow [aria-autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-autocomplete.).

The TextInput in `react-native` follows it's own [API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.65/textinput#autocompletetype-android). But there's [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26003) that renamed the prop in react native from `autoCompleteType` to `autoComplete`. So at the time of writing the React Native docs also need to be updated.

**The solution:**

```
<TextInput
  autoComplete={ Platform.OS === 'web' ? 'none' : 'off' }
```

Tested in:

```
expo: 42.0.4
react-native: 0.63.2 (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz)
react-native-web (version): 0.13.18
react: 16.13.1
Browser: Chrome 96.0.4664.110
```

Answer (score 2):

The prop you need to pass is `autoCompleteType='off'`. You can find more information on the props for the react-native provided TextInput component (who's props React Native Paper's TextInput also extends) here. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#autocompletetype

Comment: You can check here : https://snack.expo.io/@kopax/curious-pizza-2 it does not help. Keep in mind I target the web with it, and the resulting html is what you should take in consideration.

Comment: I believe `autoCompleteType` is only for Android & the property is suppose to be `autoComplete='off'` according to this update: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26003.  But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

for ios  textContentType={'none'}